# Shiny Server on Centos configuration

Tags: r, centos, shiny, shiny-server, rstudio-server

I recently installed `shiny-server` on my Centos 7 server. (`centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64`)

I am unable to get the server started however, and it appears it's not looking for the right config file on boot. I have my my `shiny-server.conf` file in the default location of `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`

Trace:

`[2016-08-03 00:25:52.907] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.4.2.786 (Node.js v0.10.40)
[2016-08-03 00:25:52.911] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/root/start"
[2016-08-03 00:25:52.926] [ERROR] shiny-server - Error loading config: File "/root/start" does not exist
[2016-08-03 00:25:52.926] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes`

Apparently it's just looking in `root/start`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you get any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sudo systemctl start shiny-server`

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.